# ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed error?

Tags: python

I have a code where I am using pd.read_csv to read multiple files through loops and then also calculate ADX (trading indicator). But when I am using this, I get ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed error.

```
df['adx'] = ta.trend.adx(df['High'],df['Low'],df['Close'])
```

Here is the line of code which gave me error.

Comment: What is your question? What kind of answer do you expect? The obvious answer "do not use negative dimensions" is already implied by the error message. We cannot tell you any more without knowing what you are trying to do (as in what did you expect to happen when using negative dimensions) and the code (as a minimal, reproducible example) you are using for it.

Comment: What library are you using to calculate the adx ?